# How to place an asp:Literal underneath an asp:TextBox inside of a table

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a table, inside the table I have an asp:TextBox and an asp:Literal inside of the same data cell. Is there a way to place the Literal underneath the Textbox instead of beside the Textbox?

```
<td align="center">
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtTons" CssClass="tonnage" runat="server"
                       OnChange="txtTons_TextChanged(this)"MaxLength="6" 
                       Width="40" pattern="^\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$"></asp:TextBox>
      <asp:Literal ID="litMaxTons" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by placing both the asp:Textbox and asp:Literal inside of a div and then applying a style to each div.

```
<div style="position:relative; height:100%;">
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtTons" CssClass="tonnage" runat="server"
                       OnChange="txtTons_TextChanged(this)"
                       MaxLength="6" Width="40" pattern="^\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$">
      </asp:TextBox>
</div>
<div style="position:relative; bottom:0; color:red">
      <asp:Literal ID="litMaxTons" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</div>
```